# How to make Header Logo Responsive For Larger Screen width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design, responsive

I have created header for one of website where logo is working fine for device width of 2000 but for width of 3000 or 4000px it moves toward centre which I don't want I want it to the fixed position at header. I have added required HTML and CSS . FOR mobile tab and desktop with max-width 1400 its working fine but after that if I keep increasing width the logo starts to move toward center. i am not getting how to make it fix like it should not move toward center if I increase screen resolution

FOR SCREEN SIZE - 1400px
[image]

FOR SCREEN SIZE - 5000px
[image]

So as you can see for larger screen it had moved to center

```
<header>
    <div class="gtlLogo-wrapper brandedHeader lesssWidth" id="logo">
     <a href="service.html" class="alogoCo alogoLogo remove_left"title="alogo .com"></a> 
     <span class="branded-VerticalLine co-verticalllin" id="branded-VerticalLine"></span>
    <div class="brandedPubLogoPenny" id="brandedPubLogoPenny" style="background-image: 
     url(&quot;/imageserver/branded/publisher/113048944_Logo.svg&quot;);"></div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
    header {
        background-color: #fff;
    }
    
    element.style {
    }
        @media only screen and (min-width: 750px) and (orientation: portrait), only screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape)
    #main_header .lesssWidth {
        display: flex;
        margin: auto;
        width: 100%!important;
        max-width: 635px!important;
        padding: 17px 20px!important;
    }
#main_header #logo {
        max-width: unset;
        width: 30%;
    }
    #main_header #logo {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 130px;
    }
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1025px)
    header {
        width: 100%;
    }
#main_header #logo {
        max-width: unset;
        width: 27%;
    }
    }
    
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1400px)
    #main_header .lesssWidth {
        max-width: 1012px!important;
    }
    }
    
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1800px)
    #main_header .lesssWidth {
        max-width: 151px!important;
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 2000px)
    #main_header .lesssWidth {
        max-width: 1211px!important;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS property justify-content on #main_header .lesssWidth

Comment: It will move a littlie but not exactly actually issue is with the max-width like like max-width : 1012px!important is for 1400px but on increasing size of screen this 1012px varies  . i mean max-width needed diif- diff for diff devices